# Basic Complex Number Questions

Tags: complex-numbers

I have just started learning about complex numbers, so I would appreciate if any of you can show me the solutions to the following $2$ questions.

Solve for $z$ and write your answer in rectangular form:

1. $(3+2i)z=(5-i)+2z$
2. ${z}^{2}+6z=-13$

Comment: The first one requires complex division, the second one uses quadratic formula. Do you know them?

Answer (score 2):

1.
$$\begin{align*}
(3+2i)z &= 5-i+2z\\
(1+2i)z &= 5-i\\
z &= \frac{5-i}{1+2i}\\
&= \frac{5-i}{1+2i}\cdot\frac{1-2i}{1-2i}\\
&= \cdots
\end{align*}$$

---

2.
$$\begin{align*}
z^2 + 6z &= -13\\
z^2 + 6z + 13 &= 0\\
z &= \frac{-6 \pm \sqrt{6^2-4\cdot 13}}2\\
&= \cdots
\end{align*}$$

Comment: If you don't want to have to do complex division, you can let $z=a+bi$ and solve for $a$ and $b$ by equating the real and complex parts on each side of the equals sign. But complex division works too.

Answer (score 1):

For the quadratic equation, you can complete the square:
$$z^2=6z=(z+3)^2-9,$$
whence the equation:
$$(z+3)^2=-4\iff z+3=\pm 2\mkern1mu\mathrm i\iff z=-3\pm2\mkern1mu\mathrm i.$$